# Operand data type time is invalid for add or subtract operators

Tags: sql-server, time, operator

I'll to calculate how many hours a person has worked on SQL server. For that I'm storing the `Arrival`, `Departure` and `Break` in my database table as `time(7)`. A `bit` for `DepartureNextDay` determinate that the `Departure` is on or after midnight or not.

Here is an example of my data:

```
| ID | Arrival  | Depatrure | Break    | DepartureNextDay |
| -- | -------- | --------- | -------- | ---------------- |
| 1  | 23:00:00 | 01:00:00  | 00:00:00 | 1                |
| 2  | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00  | 01:00:00 | 0                |
```

Now I'll calculate the worked hours using this formula:

```
Departure - Arrival - Break
```

When `DepartureNextDay` is `1` there must 24 hours being added to `Departure` to get a positive result. So the results must be this:

```
| ID | WorkedHours | 
| -- | ----------- |
| 1  | 02:00:00    |
| 2  | 08:00:00    |
```

For this I'm using this code:

```sql
select (Departure + (case DepartureNextDay 
                         when 1 then convert(time(7), '24:00:00') --> this is invalid too because it's bigger then 23:59:59
                         else convert(time(7), '00:00:00')
                      end
                    )) - Arrival - Break as WorkedHours 
from WorkTable
```

But I've this error:

> Operand data type `time` is invalid for add/subtract *(when case is removed)* operator.

How could I do this?

**P.S.:** I'm storing the `DepartureNextDay` on a different column because:

1. `time(7)` must between `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` *(most important reason)*
2. It's more logical to store 1 o'clock A.M. as `01:00:00` and not as `1.01:00:00` or `25:00:00` and keep `DepartureNextDay` in a different column.

Comment: IMHO you should use datetime columns and avoid formulas.

Comment: Have you considered the case of someone working with DepartureNextDay  on the day that daylights saving changes?

Comment: @MartinSmith: All the times must be entered using the same timezone

Answer (score 1):

You should use `datetime` instead of `time`, nevertheless it is also possible using your current data:

```
;with temp
AS
(
    SELECT t.ID,
    CAST(t.Arrival AS time(7)) Arrival,
    CAST(t.Departure AS time(7)) Departure,
    CAST(t.[Break] AS time(7)) [Break],
    DepartureNextDate
    FROM (
        VALUES
        (1, '23:00:00', '01:00:00', '00:00:00', 1),
        (2, '08:00:00', '17:00:00', '01:00:00', 0)
    )t(ID, Arrival, Departure, [Break], DepartureNextDate)

)
SELECT ID, CONVERT(time(7),
    CAST(Departure AS Datetime) 
    + DATEADD(DAY, DepartureNextDate, '') 
    - CAST(Arrival AS Datetime)
    - CAST([Break] AS Datetime)
    )
FROM temp
```

Answer (score 0):

A thing you could do without changing the datatypes is to convert form `hh:mm:ss` to the decimal representations. For that you can

1. Create a function for calculate time to float:

   ```
   create function CalculateTimeAsFloat(
       @input time(7)
   ) returns float
   as begin
       return datepart(hour, @input) + 
              datepart(minute, @input) * (1.0 / 60.0) + 
              datepart(second, @input) * (1.0 / 3600.0)
   end
   ```
2. Create a function for calculate float to time:

   ```
   create function CalculateFloatAsTime(
       @input float
   ) returns time(7)
   as begin
       declare @hours float = floor(@input);
       declare @minutes float = (@input - @hours) * 60.0;
       declare @seconds float = (@minutes - floor(@minutes)) * 60.0;

       declare @text nvarchar(max) = convert(nvarchar, @hours) + ':' + 
                                     convert(nvarchar, floor(@minutes)) + ':' +
                                     convert(nvarchar, @seconds)

       return convert(time(7), @text);
   end
   ```
3. And then do your formula:

   ```
   select dbo.CalculateFloatAsTime(
           dbo.CalculateTimeAsFloat(Departure) + (case DepartureNextDay when 1 then 24 else 0 end) - 
           dbo.CalculateTimeAsFloat(Arrival) - 
           dbo.CalculateTimeAsFloat(Break)
       ) as WorkedHours
   from WorkTable
   ```

**Edit:** Found that my function in step 2 is not 100% working. I've updated it to this code:

```
alter function CalculateFloatAsTime(
    @input float
) returns time(7)
as begin
    declare @hours float = floor(@input);
    declare @minutes float = (@input - @hours) * 60.0;
    declare @seconds float = round((@minutes - floor(@minutes)) * 60.0, 0);

    declare @text nvarchar(max) = convert(nvarchar, @hours) + ':' + 
                                  convert(nvarchar, floor(@minutes) + (case @seconds when 60 then 1 else 0 end)) + ':' +
                                  convert(nvarchar, @seconds - (case @seconds when 60 then 60 else 0 end));

    return convert(time(7), @text);
end
```

An exceptions will be thrown when `@input` is 8.16666. It's a rounding error from step 1 and must be 8.16667. Because of that I've added the cases.

**Note:** This is not 100% correct when using seconds and milliseconds. There are rounding errors happening!